# Floated div wraps in table-cell if container is smaller than 169 px

Tags: css

Two divs (red and yellow) should always be side by side using the float:left property. But when the width of the container div becomes "too small", than the yellow div pops below the red div.

https://jsfiddle.net/vt5zf3z0/

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="first">
          <div class="innerFirst">Blablub</div>
      </div>
      <div class="second">
          <div class="innerSecond">When the container is smaller than 169px, than the yellow div pops below the red div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Currently, the the container becomes "too small" when the width < 169px in Firefox and the width < 167x in Chrome.

How to keep the red and the yellow div side by side in a smaller container?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vt5zf3z0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `display:table-cell` from innerFirst and innerSecond.
2. Remove `display:table` from `.first` and `.second` and add `display:table-cell` to both of them.
3. Add `display:table` to `.container`

https://jsfiddle.net/vt5zf3z0/2/

Comment: The suggested solution shows both DIVs side by side because of setting the display property to `display:table-cell`. But one question still remains: Why does the `float:left` property from the first [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vt5zf3z0/) only work for a container width >= 169px?